# how to create details page in typo3 v9 news system

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

I created the news page (list view) but the details are not shown.
I tried to create a detail page to which I added the news detail plugin but it shows error

The page shows
`Oops, an error occurred!
TypoScript object path "lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering" does not exist
More information regarding this error might be available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did was
create a page by adding the news plug-in this configuration: What to show: List view, Category selection, Starting point: Your News folder. Additional: PageId for unique news display: Your list view page, PageId for list display:
and pageId for the detail view previously create another detail page
- Starting point only the NewsFolder. (Creating a folder)
and add this in typoscript this code

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a details page, you only need one News element (for List and Datail) and you have also to set "PageId for single news display" the same page as the element.

Comment: I see this error:
Oops, an error occurred!
TypoScript object path "lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering" does not exist
More information regarding this error might be available

Comment: please if you could give me more detail of your answer

Comment: You have News 7.2

Comment: News Settings: 
    What to display: List View, 
    Category selection, 
    Startingpoint: your News folder. 

Additional: 
    PageId for single news display: Your list view page, 
    PageId for list display: Your list view page, 
    PageId to return to: Your list view page, 
    Disable override demand: yes

Comment: the News folder must be created and must be empty ?. and how to create News folder by UI? @HelmutWinkelbach please your help is being very important so far. here screenshot [link](https://ibb.co/fCYZ5Kw)

Comment: Yes, 
I'm using  News 7.2

Comment: You should read the manual. Everything is described in detail. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/7.2.0/

Comment: Does your news folder contain the news plugin?
All your news should be in your NewsFolder.
Startingpoint only the NewsFolder.

Comment: did you actually include the static template?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas 
 What do you mean by static template?

Comment: Go to your Template module on the left side, then select your root page and press „edit the whole template“. Switch to the include tabs and see if the news system is included on the left side of the list. Make sure the style fluid content or something like that is included as well

Comment: added the configuration in NewsFolder, but I get this 
`Oops, an error occurred!
No Content Object definition found at TypoScript object path "lib.yourownTypoScript"
More information regarding this error might be available` when I click on "read more"  @HelmutWinkelbach

Comment: Quit difficult to help as we do not know what you did, studying the Docu helps a lot. Did you have a look at this? [link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/7.2.0/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/IntegrationWithTypoScript/Index.html)

Have a look at: List and detail on the same page using TypoScript

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add all needed typoscript configurations for extension. Edit your template and include static from extension. You should read the manual too. Everything is described in detail. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/7.2.0

Comment: that is, is it not enough to copy the UI configurations? @HeinzSchilling

Comment: Have you read the chapter "For administrators > Installation"? Do all the steps described there and then read "For editors". The author of the extension invested time in the fine documentation.